# How $x \mod 2$ is in Elementary?

Tags: functions, computational-complexity

The function $$x\mapsto x\mod 2$$
should be in the complexity class [Elementary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELEMENTARY) (click it to see the definition of wikipedia). But using the definition, I don't see how to combine the functions to obtain the modulo. It should even be lower elementary (no need of the product)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With $$ x\dot-y=\begin{cases}x-y&\text{if }x\ge y\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
and $$u(x)=(2\dot- x)\dot-((1\dot-x)+(1\dot-x))=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }x=1\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
we have
$$ x\bmod 2=\sum_{k=0}^xu(x\dot-(k+k))$$
so we need only addition, (cut-off) subtraction and bounded summation

Comment: Nice answer, I feel ashamed of not finding it !